$\sum (-1)^n a_n $ that satisfies the Ratio Test but does not satisfy the Leibniz Test
I'm trying to find an example of an alternating series $\sum (-1)^n a_n $ that satisfies the Ratio Test but does not satisfy the Leibniz Test.
To provide more context I will write in detail here. The Leibniz test for alternating series says that if $(a_n)$ is a monotone decreasing  sequence ($a_{n+1}<a_{n}$, for all $n \in \mathbb{N}$) and $a_n \rightarrow 0$ when $n \rightarrow \infty$ then the series $\sum (-1)^na_n$ is convergent.
Consider the series $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} (-1)^n (\frac{3}{4})^n$ then clearly this series satisfies the Ratio test as well as Leibniz.
More specifically, we have:
$$-\frac{3}{4}+\left(\frac{3}{4}\right)^2-\left(\frac{3}{4}\right)^3+\left(\frac{3}{4}\right)^4-\cdots.$$
From the comments and the answer below, the only way to find a series that satisfies the ratio test and does not satisfy Leibniz is by modifying the first terms of the series. Therefore, we just need to define
$$\frac{1}{2}-\frac{3}{4}+\left(\frac{3}{4}\right)^2-\left(\frac{3}{4}\right)^3+\left(\frac{3}{4}\right)^4-\cdots.$$
So $a_1>a_2$.

What do you mean by 'satisfying' a test?

@Yathi $\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty}\left| \frac{a_{n+1}}{a_n}\right|=L<1$ for the ratio test.

What do you mean by not satisfying Leibniz test?

Either $\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} a_n \neq 0$ or $(a_n)$ is not decreasing.

The ratio test for $a_n$ implies that $a_n$ is decreasing to for large $n

It's not possible, assuming all $a_n\geq0$ since satisfying the ratio test implies convergence, and failing the Leibniz test implies non convergence (since limit going to $0$ is a necessary condition for convergence)
